# How to display the QR-code in popup box using java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qr-code

I am using the QRcode.js from https://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/ and it is working fine on my webpage, But I want to show this Generated qr code in dialog/alert box using java script. Can anyone help me how can I do that?

Comment: By alertbox you mean window.alert()? If yes: This is not possible. If a popup (in terms of a new browser window) also works for you check window.open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap Modal here. Just put `<div id="qrcode"></div>` inside modal body, and done.

Here is how to use Bootstrap Modal - [Bootstrap Modal](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/)

Answer (score 0):

Below code use bootstrap to display the QR Code generated by qrcode.js in a popup box:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a tabindex="0" role="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="bottom" title="QR Code" data-url="https://www.gloomycorner.com">Popover QR Code</a>
  <div id="qrcode" style="display:none; width:auto; height:auto;padding:15px;"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), {
    width: 120,
    height: 120
  });

  function makeQrcode(e) {
    qrcode.makeCode(e.attr("data-url"));
  }
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("[data-toggle='popover']").popover(
      options = {
        content: jQuery("#qrcode"),
        html: true // important! popover html content (tag: "#qrcode") which contains an image
      }
    );

    jQuery("[data-toggle='popover']").on("show.bs.popover", function(e) {
      makeQrcode(jQuery(this));
      jQuery("#qrcode").show();
    });
  });
</script>
```

[How to generate a qr code and display it in a popup box](https://www.gloomycorner.com/how-to-generate-a-qr-code-and-display-it-in-a-popup-box/?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=website) gives a full example.

Screenshot of the example:

[image: qr code sample]